# Yahoo Screenscraping software

Tags: screen-scraping, yahoo

Some time ago, I came across something Yahoo offers to do screen scraping and for the life of me I cannot find it again. It is not Pipes and it is not YQL and I know I found it on Stack.

Can someone please help remind me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must mean [Dapper](http://open.dapper.net/).